# convert ngnix rails conf to apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I am trying to set up apache in production server. My nginx configuration is shown below.

```
upstream puma {
   server unix:///var/www/rails/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;
}

server {
   listen 80 default_server deferred;
   # server_name example.com;

   root /var/www/rails/current/public;
   access_log /var/www/rails/current/log/nginx.access.log;
   error_log /var/www/rails/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

   location ^~ /assets/ {
     gzip_static on;
     expires max;
     add_header Cache-Control public;
   }

   try_files $uri @puma;
   location @puma {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_pass http://puma;
   }

   error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
   client_max_body_size 10M;
   keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

But I couldn't find how to specify socket in httpd configuration. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To set the port an Apache server listens on, use the `Listen` directive.

Here’s what it says in the default `httpd.conf` file (found in `/etc/apache2/` in the apache2 install I’m using — although different installs/systems put the config directory in other locations):

```
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
#Listen 66.18.208.111:80
#Listen 66.18.208.112:80
Listen 80
```

If you are using named virtual hosts (multiple websites on one server) you’ll want to see the instructions for the `NameVirtualHost` and `VirtualHost` directives in [Apache 2.2 vhosts documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)

Comment: yes, we can use <VirtualHost *:80> in apache. But how to replace the line *RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3000%{REQUEST_URI} [P]* with socket file name

Comment: puma server is started using the command **bundle exec puma -C /var/www/rails/shared/puma.rb --daemon** without any port

Comment: Oh, there’s no mention of a rewrite rule in your original post. Can you edit the question to clarify what you're trying to figure out, please? In any case, you want the documentation for the Apache `rewrite_module` ModRewrite: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Previosly, I was running rails on port 3000, then we were able to use *RewriteRule ^/(.)$ 127.0.0.1:3000%{REQUEST_URI} [P]* in apache conf, and was working. But when using capistrano its running using the command *** bundle exec puma -C /var/www/rails/shared/puma.rb --daemon*** .

Comment: Oh — so it’s an issue with how Capistrano is installing things? If that’s the case, you may want to either significantly edit your question, or post a new question, because your current question at the top of this post makes no mention of Capistrano. (I don’t use Capistrano, so can’t address questions about it.)

Comment: ok, thank you for the time. Now currently I am able to run puma in a port by adding bind in puma.rb file, ***bind 'tcp://0.0.0.0:3000'***